# How can we cause two nodes at different potential to be at the same potential?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, electronics, electrical-engineering

I read it somewhere that when two nodes intended to be at different potential are forced to be at same potential, it causes short circuit. So, when we get shocks, does that happen due to this short circuit thing. what exactly can i do to put two nodes at different potential to be at the same potential? And, how does that happen? Like why do we say or how can we say that these terminals or nodes are at the same potential?

Answer (score 0):

A short circuit is the introduction of an alternative (low resistance) path for the current to flow between two nodes in a circuit.
It is often associated with the resistance being very low compared to other resistances in the circuit or zero in an ideal case.
When your body makes a conducting path between two nodes of an electrical circuit a current will flow through you.
If the voltage is high enough and your resistance is low enough then sufficient charge will flow through you for it to have an effect on you.
You will feel a shock or in an extreme case case be electrocuted.
Touching the mains supply live and neutral or live conductors with wet hands rather than dry hands decreases the contact resistance and hence increases the current which can pass through you.
If as in the case of a mains supply there are power supplies, batteries etc which maintain a potential difference across the nodes connected together with a conductor (short circuit) a current will continuously flow through the short circuit and that current can be very large if the resistance of the short circuit is very low.
The purpose of the fuse or circuit breaker is stop the current flowing if the current exceeds a specified value.
However if you short out the positive and negative terminals of a low voltage battery the chances are you will not feel a shock although you have introduced a short circuit between the two batter terminals.
Some people are able to feel an effect of a 9 V PP3 type battery when the terminals of the battery are placed on their tongue.  The short circuit (moist tongue) having a low enough resistance for a noticeable current to flow even though the voltage is relatively low.

[image]

If there is not a voltage supply, battery etc in a circuit then if two two charged objects (nodes), eg the plates of a charged capacitor, are connected together with a short circuit then charge will flow through the short circuit until the potential difference between the two plates (nodes) becomes zero.
So in electrostatic connecting two conductors with a piece of wire will result in those two conductors reaching the same potential.